# Importing elevation data into prexisting KML in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: kml, elevation, google-earth-pro

I am working on a project where I need the z value (elevation) of a set of data points.

Is there a way to assign elevation data to a KML in Google Earth without doing it manually for each point?

I have tried using TCX converter and http://www.nearby.org.uk/elevation-kml.php with no luck.

Comment: This might work better for you http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/elevation

Comment: How big is your KML file, how many points, and more importantly, how is it being generated?  You most likely will want to add the elevations to the points when the KML is generated, likely with some flavor of GIS software.  Once the file is loaded in Earth, there's no way to modify it other than editing the points one by one.  Also, you'll probably need your own elevation dataset, since Earth will let  you visualize its elevation/terrain data just fine, but the terms of service don't allow bulk extraction of data.

Answer (score 1):

If you have points that can be add to Google Earth Pro and create a path across them you can use the elevation profile along a path.

This image gives you an example:

[image]

There you can interactively scroll along the path.

Save this path out and use gpsvisualiser to get elevations.